# Lower level of wireless signal on an Intel Centrino Wireless-N + Wimax 6150

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless

I am sitting next to my router and I don't see full wireless signal since I upgraded from ubuntu 11.04 64bit to ubuntu 12.04 
and I noticed more battery usage in my laptop , since I upgraded . (that makes sense when the wireless signal is weak the laptop uses more energy)

my wireless card is 
 Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 (rev 67)

I have toshiba Satellite-P745

Answer (score 0):

You can view your wireless connection details by entering command `sudo iwconfig`.Well if you want to increase the speed manually, then you can try manipulating the configuration of your wireless by changing the following modes:

```
Encryption=off
mode=G
rate=54M
```

try entering command `sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M` if this can solve the problem. Else you can try to go to [following page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/iwconfig.8.html) to have a look at command list and set the command at iwconfig to following mode I describes to have wireless at its best configuration.